# cache wav file using javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, wav

When I load a sound file with Javascript, the file seems to load from remote server each time.  Is it possible to cache the file once loaded? I would like to load once and play as required.

```
    var soundEmbed = null;
    function playSound()
{   
    var myWAVfile = "myfile.wav";
        if (soundEmbed)
    {
       document.body.removeChild(soundEmbed);
    }
    soundEmbed = document.createElement("embed");
    soundEmbed.setAttribute("src", myWAVfile);
    soundEmbed.setAttribute("hidden", true);
    soundEmbed.setAttribute("autostart", true);
    document.body.appendChild(soundEmbed);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the response headers?  If the server isn't configured for caching, you can't fix it with javascript.

Comment: Caching is browser dependent behavior that you don't really have control over. This should be a case where most browsers would want to save this file locally. What browsers are you testing in?